# how to verify shortcut installation on android

Tags: android, android-intent, shortcut

I have an issue that i need some clarification with. I am creating a shortcut with the following code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("duplicate",false);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, MYOTHERINTENT);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1)).getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null,new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("in broadcast process","isorderedbroadcast:"+isOrderedBroadcast()+"/"+System.currentTimeMillis());
            Log.d("in broadcast process","resultcode:"+getResultCode()+":"+getResultData());
        }
    }, null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
```

I have 2 issues that I am trying to work through.

1) Can I verify the icon was created successfully or not. (return code was a success even when the icon was not created due to lack of available space)
2) Can I properly detect what shortcuts exist or verify the existence of my icon on the homescreen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I verify the icon was created successfully or not

No.

> Can I properly detect what shortcuts exist or verify the existence of my icon on the homescreen?

No. Bear in mind that not all home screen implementations will honor this broadcast, as there is no requirement that they do so. Adding a shortcut to a home screen is something you are welcome to try, but you cannot rely upon it being supported on any given device.